# How does nuget execute entity framework's seed method via command line

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, nuget

`I am using dapper as my ORM, and I've been a long time entity framework user. I'd like to execute a custom seed method of my own similar, to how entity framework code first works via nuget "update-database" but i'm not sure exactly how that works. I've searched through the package and looked at tools folder at the *.ps1 files and see in the help file that is included in the package that

```
The following Entity Framework cmdlets are used with Entity Framework
Migrations.

    Cmdlet              Description
    -----------------   ---------------------------------------------------
    Enable-Migrations   Enables Code First Migrations in a project.

    Add-Migration       Scaffolds a migration script for any pending model
                        changes.

    Update-Database     Applies any pending migrations to the database.

    Get-Migrations      Displays the migrations that have been applied to
                        the target database
```

I'm guessing the commandlets live inside of entityframework.powershell.dll?

my question is: is there a way i could toss a powershell file in with my dapper package to allow me to call seed-database within nuget, and then fire off a custom seed method similar to entity frameworks, and is the code for the entity framework commandlets "update-database" out there somewhere for me to see how they trigger the C# seed method.